# closing tabs in the tabcontrol using c#

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

I am creating multiple tabs dynamically when my application starts up.
Put it this way, if my tabcontrol have two tabs in it, which calls Notepad
and ms paint.

when the notepad is closed.... I want my tab respective to notepad to be closed in
my tabcontrol.

How ?

Comment: How does a tab "call Notepad"? I think we need to see some code.

Comment: each tab is created when my application calls a batch file.
I specified in the question as Notepad because, so that it would be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to say that you want a tab removed?  Tabs aren't really open or closed.

Here's how you'd remove a tab:

```
myTabControl.TabPages.Remove(notepadTab);
```

where *notepadTab* is a reference to the tab associated with the notepad application.  You've stated that pages are created dynamically - have a look at the function overloads of Remove( ) to find one that suits your needs.